# Get value for each model field with _meta

Tags: python, django, django-models

In my model, I have a method for getting `verbose_name` for each field with _meta. How can I get value for each field similar way with _meta?

```
class Description(models.Model):
    name = models.OneToOneField(Breeds, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    history = models.TextField()
    nature = models.TextField()
    care = models.TextField()
    feed = models.TextField()
    health = models.TextField()
    some_facts = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name.breed

    def get_verbose_name(self):
        return [field.verbose_name for field in Description._meta.fields]
```

I want to get values similar to the `get_verbose_name` method.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking.

Comment: I have a method what return verbose_name for each field in model. How can i get stored data for each field in model ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain the values by using `field.get_attname()` to obtain the name of the attribute, and then access `getattr(self, field.get_attname())`:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
        
    # …
    
    def get_values(self):
        return {
            field.name: getattr(self, field.get_attname())
            for field in cls._meta.fields
        }
```

This will then return a dictionary that maps the field names to the corresponding object.

or as a list of values:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
        
    # …
    
    def get_values(self):
        return [
            getattr(self, field.get_attname())
            for field in cls._meta.fields
        ]
```

Comment: @Nick: but you get the corresponding value with `getattr(self, field.get_attname())`. Using a list however does not make much sense, since how do you know what value belongs to what field?

Comment: I want obtain the data stored in the field, not a names.

For exaple. I have get one product stored in my model.i wath to obtain names and data stored in model for thi product.

Then i to want do loop for names and values, and display on the page. Instead of creating many similar collspane code blocks.

Comment: @Nick: I would really advise not to do that through looping over the two lists, since there are no hard guarantees that the order will be exactly the same. Although likely so, you can see it as an implementation detail, that might change eventually.

Comment: Ok. I create another question about collapse today. Maybe you can help please ?

https://stackoverflow.com/q/63202488/9962169